# Does the ratio of magnetic length to geometric length of a bar magnet always remain the same?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, length

It is said that, due to end effects, the assumed poles of a bar magnet are slightly inside the ends of the magnet. The distance between the locations of the assumed poles is called the magnetic length of the magnet. The distance between the ends is called the geometrical length.

[image]

The magnetic length of a bar magnet is nearly $0.84$ times that of the geometric length, which looks quite valid. What would happen if I cut the same bar magnet along the magnetic axis or along a direction perpendicular to the magnetic axis? Would the new poles arrange themselves in order to maintain the same ratio?

Further, is this ratio same for all kinds of magnet independent of the material and geometry?

Comment: Could you define the term *magnetic length* within the question? It's not *that* common.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: Any inputs?

Comment: @ACuriousMind: I've added some details to the question. Could you tell whether it is clear now?

Comment: Magnets don't actually contain poles, so it's unclear what "magnetic length" means.

Comment: @knzhou: Thanks. I understood your point as it due to the fact magnetic monopoles have not been found yet. However, my textbook says the magnetic field due to a circular current carrying loop can be considered to be equal to that of a magnetic dipole. And in bar magnets the distance between theoretical monopoles is the "magnetic length".

Comment: @GuruVishnu Well, all I can say is that I've seen a lot of Indian physics textbooks, such as H.C. Verma, and they make a _lot_ of definitions that don't really make sense as written... it seems this term is rarely used anywhere outside of India, does not have a clear definition in the Indian books, and only appears as something you have to memorize because it's used in IIT JEE problems. Googling the term, all of the top 10 results are from India, and most of them use the exact same diagram.

Comment: @GuruVishnu I would advise you to just memorize the number $0.84$, use it completely blindly to pass your exams, and then completely forget about it.

Comment: @knzhou 1) [Landau Levels and Magnetic length](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/110276/249968) 2)[Why enthalpy change at constant volume is being stated as change in internal energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46657/249968). These are some of the posts on magnetic length on physics.SE and don't seem to be from Indian textbooks.

Comment: @Johan Liebert These are completely unrelated uses of the phrase.

Comment: Magnetic length is the distance between the two poles of a magnet. I wonder how exact location can be found.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it will remain constant. Because of this property magnetic strength remains constant when cut transversally.