# Confusion regarding magnetic length

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

Consider the geometric length of a magnet to be $L$ and magnetic length to be $L'$.

Some sources claim that $L'$ = $(0.84)L$.

One such claim can be found here:-
[image]

[image]

I cannot find any good reason to be satisfied with the expression. Is the above equation true for all cases? If so why?

Comment: Do you have any hint as to how this book is defining "magnetic south/north pole"? This somehow seems to be a concept taught to younger students, but it isn't really mentioned in any real (college + level) textbooks. I wonder if it's even a real concept. This post seems to indicate https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/168501/does-the-ratio-of-magnetic-length-to-geometric-length-of-a-bar-magnet-always-rem that it's something only taught in Indian textbooks, and its definition or justification is never provided.

Comment: This quora post gives some kind of hint that it's a material science fact about magnets made of rare earth metals. But they still dont define "the position of the poles" or derive the number. So I wouldn't worry too much about understanding this, probably nonsense, concept. https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-effective-length-of-a-bar-magnet-taken-to-be-85-of-its-geometrical-length